# Jest mock function arguments don't match when using immutable data structures

Tags: javascript, immutable.js, jestjs

When trying to test the arguments passed to the function with Jest's `.toHaveBeenCalledWith()` method, the test fails if I am treating with immutable data structures using ImmutableJS library. The test fails with the message similar to this:

```
Expected mock function to have been called with:
  [{"foo": true, "bar": "baz"}]
But it was called with:
  [{"foo": true, "bar": "baz"}]
```

The test looks similar to this:

```
const expectedArgs = Map({
  foo: true,
  bar: 'baz'
});

const foo = jest.fn();
bar();
expect(foo).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedArgs);
```

And the function similar to this:

```
const bar = () => {
  const baz = Map({});
  const bazModified = baz.set('foo', true).set('bar', 'baz');
  foo(bazModified);
}
```

I realized that if I pass the arguments in this manner everything works fine:

```
const bar = () => {
  const baz = Map({
    foo: true,
    bar: 'baz'
  });
  foo(baz);
}
```

The problem is that this is a big simplification of my function's logic and I have to use .set to construct the object. Does anybody have an idea why the approach with .set is failing to evaluate correctly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So your test is failing because `toHaveBeenCalledWith` only passes if the instances of the entities are exactly the same. It is similar to the following, which also fails:

```
const expectedArgs = Map({
  foo: true,
  bar: 'baz'
});

const input =  Map({
  foo: false,
  bar: 'baz'
});

const result = input.set('foo', true);

expect(result).toBe(expectedArgs);
```

This, on the other hand, does work:

```
expect(result).toEqual(expectedArgs);
```

Because that performs a deep equal.

There is no way you will be able to test equality with `toHaveBeenCalledWith`, because `baz.set('foo', true)` will always return a new instance (which is the point of using immutable data).

I don't think there is a way to make `toHaveBeenCalledWith` behave like `toEqual`, so I guess the way to go is to manually test the mock call with `toEqual`:

```
const expectedArgs = Map({
  foo: true,
  bar: 'baz'
});

const foo = jest.fn();
bar();
// foo.mock.calls[0][0] returns the first argument of the first call to foo
expect(foo.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual(expectedArgs);
```

See the documentation on [toBe](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#tobevalue), [toEqual](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#toequalvalue), and [mock calls](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#mockfnmockcalls)

Comment: Thank you. It was the "exactly the same" part that I was getting wrong. Thought it just needed to match a particular parameter.